# Script to make configuration changes to all versions of web.config file

Tags: powershell, iis, iis-7, iis-8

I have 4 web.config files in 4 different locations:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\web.config
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\web.config
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config
```

I would like to run the below command and make configuration changes to all the 4 web.config files.

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /commit:WEBROOT /section:system.web/httpCookies /httpOnlyCookies:true
```

Is there any way to make the changes in all the web.config files?

Comment: or even the below command can be used

Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath "MACHINE/WEBROOT" -filter system.web/httpCookies -name httpOnlyCookies -value:True